# Exec Bad Access when clicking a button on SubView

Tags: ios, ios5, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a main view to which I have added a subview using the following code:

```
-(IBAction)launchPage:(id) sender
{
    ActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:nil];
    activityViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(183, 104, 841, 573);
    activityViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"activity_bckgrnd.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:activityViewController.view];    
}
```

I have buttons on this xib file to which I am trying to add button events. But when I click on the button after assigning `IBAction`, I am getting an EXEC BAD ACCESS error at

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what the mistake might be. I have enabled ARC for the project.

In .h file of view controller that I have added as subview, I have declared

```
@property(strong,retain) UIButton *billingAddressChkBox;
```

and in the .m file, The IBAction looks like

```
- (IBAction)checkboxButton:(id)sender{

if (checkboxSelected == 0){
    [billingAddressChkBox setSelected:YES];
    checkboxSelected = 1;

} else {
    [billingAddressChkBox setSelected:NO];
    checkboxSelected = 0;
}
```

}

I have enabled zombies and I get the following message.

```
message sent to deallocated instance
```

Can I know which instance is getting deallocated from its address?

Comment: Yes. I am using ARC because I need the project from 5.0 and up

Comment: While debugging, can you step through the `launchPage` method line by line and see which line gives you the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Comment: post the code where you add the event to the button

Comment: While debugging its not going inside the method which I have linked with IBAction. The error occurs as soon as I click the button.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 and http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2 The tutorial helped me with many debug-related issues

Comment: Please put some more code your button action etc.. is you button strong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to just initialize

```
ActivityViewController *activityViewController
```

in the header file and access it from the .m file. That solved the issue.

Comment: Exactly. It helps me. Maybe because of ARC so we need to create a Controller as property

Comment: Great !! +1 .... But Can any one tell me why this ? Why we cant make it local .... why we need to declare it in .h file ? :-o

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ARC, you use the `strong` property option instead of the MRC `retain` property option. 
So when you write `@property(strong,retain) UIButton *billingAddressChkBox;`, remove the `retain` and I believe it should work.

Hope this helps!